# Balance objects over two columns using CSS column-count: 2 in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created a dashboard solution in which objects of ever changing height are stacked in two columns. The goal is to distribute the objects over the columns as follows:

1. First object goes top left in first column
2. Next object goes below that object, unless there is not enough space to fit the full height of the object, if object doesn't fit, put it in the second column.
3. If object doesn't fit in free space in second column, then distribute objects over columns to achieve two columns with same height and make container div scrollable.

Objects don't have a fixed height, an object can be empty on Monday and taking up the entire left column on Tuesday.

I created the following:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='columncontainer'>
    <span id='span1'>Block1</span>
    <span id='span2'>Block2</span>
    <span id='span3'>Block3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
#container{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

#columncontainer {
  column-count: 2;
}

#columncontainer > span {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#span1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#span2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#span3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

The problem I have with this solution is demonstrated here and occurs in the Chrome browser:
https://jsfiddle.net/3620qgvs/

In this example the last two objects in the columns would easily fit in the second column (200+50=250 < 300).

However the first two objects are rendered in the first column and #span2 of 50px height has the entire 300px of the second column for itself.

I do want to keep objects together, so using block instead of inline-block isn't an option. (This splits objects over two columns)

My implementations which I've tried which put objects on (float)lines or (flex)grids all had the same problem; if there are two large-height objects in a left column, two small-height objects in the right column will have a lot of vertical white-space between them (whitespace between block 2 and 4 demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/3kd9r8ye/2/). Thats why I'm using column-count as this will function like "float: down" (which doesn't exist)

Any solutions or alternative approaches?

Comment: PS. The balancing between columns seems to work fine in Firefox and Edge, not in Chrome

Comment: You have the same `span id='span1'` for both `Block1` and `Block2`

Comment: That's intentional. Both of them should have a 200px height so that Block2 will be rendered in the second column because 200+200 > 300px height of the container.

Comment: If you want the both blocks to have the same height you can use a `class` instead of the `id`. You can't have a duplicated id in HTML DOM. In your case it's not the problem actually.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out, I should've noticed that. But indeed when using classes (which I am in my production code) the problem still occurs.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug at the chromium issue tracker https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=922660 still I'm looking for alternative approaches for until bug is fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that in Chrome CSS properties "orphans" and "widows" are set to a value of 2 by default, whereas other browsers seem to maintain a value of 1.

In order to fix the issue I described, the following CSS properties on #columncontainer should be added:

```
orphans: 1
widows: 1
```

This will prevent Chrome from trying to stick to one column.

For further reference:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638530
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break/#widows-orphans
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break/#unforced-breaks

Excerpt of drafts.csswg.org:

```
If a block contains fewer lines than the value of widows or orphans, the rule simply becomes that all lines in the block must be kept together.
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you. Thank you. I was thinking this was a bug in Chrome that I would have to wait out until they fixed it. They are stupid defaults because with two items, both are displayed in one column while the other is blank. But at least specifying `1` for each is not trying to trick the system as they are legitimate settings, so they don't have to be removed later.

Comment: Yeah I felt the same way :)

Comment: Note that in your first reference, the `Status` is `WontFix (Closed)`. Now that's arrogant!

Comment: Firefox ignores `widows` and `orphans`, marking them like `Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped.`. However, at least they handle columns as if both those were `1`, which is a small mercy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem seen in the `column-count` property. For your problem you can use the following solution which works fine with very few `css changes` and also I noticed in your question you've duplicated the element id which lead your HTML to invalid. So avoid it in future, work with `css classes`.

```css
#container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#columncontainer {
  /* column-count: 2;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

#columncontainer>span {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #CCCC;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.block1,
.block2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.block3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>

  <div id='columncontainer'>
    <span id='span1' class="block1">Block1</span>
    <span id='span2' class="block2">Block2</span>
    <span id='span3' class="block3">Block3</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, this setup however causes another problem. As the objects are now on a grid there will be a lot of whitespace if block1 and 2 are of different height, check the whitespace between block 2 and 4 in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kd9r8ye/2/ This is why I was using the column-count setup. Heights are variable, widths are constant (e.g. 50%). I'd need something like your solution, but with "float: down" instead of from left to right, which doesn't seem to exist

Comment: Now I got it. This is still a mysterious code. I don't understand why the order getting messed with the sibling elements.I am working on it. I will update the answer and let you know

Comment: Checkout this example. But this won't be suitable for dynamic contents. https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example32/

Comment: As it made no sense to me either I reported it as a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=922660

Comment: That's a smart work. Sometimes you can get some help of `js` and achieve it.